# Is the product of any two invertible diagonalizable matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

While studying linear algebra, I saw an example of a pair of $2 \times 2$ or $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrices, the product of which is not diagonalizable. Is there a similar example when I replace the condition "diagonalizable" by "invertible and diagonalizable"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A counterexample:$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
The result is a well known nondiagonalizable matrix, the left matrix of the product is diagonal already, and the right matrix can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\2&0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

Comment: As painfully simple as that. +!

Comment: There's a tiny typo in the last line -- the inner matrix should be diagonal.