# Under what conditions is the product of two invertible diagonalizable matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

The answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084522/is-the-product-of-any-two-invertible-diagonalizable-matrices-diagonalizable) gives an example for the statement

> product of two invertible diagonalizable matrices is not diagonalizable.

My question is:

> Are there some conditions, perhaps on the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices, under which the product of two invertible diagonalizable matrices is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  two matrices $\;A,B\;$ are simultaneously diagonalizable (and thus they commute, for example),  we get
$$\begin{cases}A=P^{-1}D_1P\\{}\\B=P^{-1}D_2P\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies AB=P^{-1}D_1D_2P$$

and clearly $\;D_1D_2\;$ is also diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to diagonalize a matrix using unitary operators, then it must be normal, i.e.

$A=UDU^\dagger$ if and only if $AA^\dagger = A^\dagger A$.

For your question, you would require that the product is normal:

$AB(AB)^\dagger=(AB)^\dagger AB$,

i.e., $ABB^\dagger A^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger A B$