# If matrix $A$ is similar to matrix $D$ and $B$ is similar to $E$, than: $AB$ is similar to $DE$?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

More specifically: if $A$ & $B$ are diagonalizeable, than is it correct to say that $AB$ is diagonalizeable? 
(Hints would be more appreciated)

Comment: Not true in general.  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215569/under-what-conditions-is-the-product-of-two-invertible-diagonalizable-matrices-d.

Comment: And the answer to the question in the title is also "no". Consider the case where $A=B=D$ is the 2x2 nilpotent Jordan block and $E=A^T$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try to see what happens in a concrete example where $A,B$ are diagonalizable but $AB \neq BA$ (so $A$ and $B$ don't commute).

Comment: In fact, any matrix over the complex numbers can be written as a product of two diagonalizable matrices (see Polar Decomposition of matrices) but not all matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: I tried an example:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
$AB\not = BA$ but $AB$ is diagonalizeable.

Answer (score 0):

we have:
$$
A=P^{-1}DP \quad \land \quad B=Q^{-1}EQ \quad \Rightarrow \quad AB=P^{-1}DPQ^{-1}EQ
$$
So we can say that if $P=Q$ ( i.e. $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable) than $AB$ is diagonalizable.