# When is the product of two non simultaneously diagonalizable matrices (one of them nonsingular but none of them positive definite) diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is an extension of [another math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215569/under-what-conditions-is-the-product-of-two-invertible-diagonalizable-matrices-d). Let $A,B$ be two (complex) square matrices which are both diagonalizable but, unlike in the aforementioned question, *not simultaneously* diagonalizable (particularly, they do *not* commute). The following facts are known:

1. (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317334/why-is-this-matrix-product-diagonalizable)) If $A,B$ are Hermitian and (say) $A$ is positive definite, then $AB$ ($=A^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}})A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$) is diagonalizable;
2. If (say) $A$ is nonsingular, then $AB$ ($=A(BA)A^{-1}$) is diagonalizable if and only if $BA$ ($=A^{-1}(AB)A$) is also diagonalizable.
3. (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084522/is-the-product-of-any-two-invertible-diagonalizable-matrices-diagonalizable)) On the other hand, there are examples where $A,B$ are both nonsingular and have only real eigenvalues, yet $AB$ is *not* diagonalizable - moreover, in the example just cited the eigenvalues of $AB$ also happen to be all real.

I am looking for conditions somewhat in between (1) and (3) which guarantee that $AB$ is diagonalizable.

More precisely, suppose that $A,B$ are Hermitian, noncommuting (complex) square matrices with $A$ nonsingular but *neither* $A$ *nor* $B$ necessarily positive definite. As (3) shows, this alone does not guarantee diagonalizability of $AB$, even if $AB$ has only real eigenvalues as well. Nonetheless,

> **Question:** Are there other conditions that can be added to the ones listed in the last paragraph above which do guarantee together that $AB$ is diagonalizable?