# If A and B are both diagonalizable, is AB also diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here are my steps:

$PAP^{-1}PBP^{-1}=PABP^{-1}=AB$, since both are diaglonalizale, the equation is established, is it correct?

Comment: Not really... it is not "the same $P$."

Comment: The answer is no, and an example can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084522/110831).

Answer (score 1):

The result is not correct as said in the comments.

However it is true when $A$ and $B$ commute. This last result can be proven as the eigenspace of one matrix is a stable subspace of the other matrix.