# The product diagonalisable matrices of determinant 1 is not necessarily diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I need to confirm, for a proof, a general result of linear algebra:

> Let $g, h \in SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ two diagonalisable (semisimple) matrices.
>   The product of these matrices is not necessarily diagonalisable.

I've tried to write $g = xdx^{-1}$ and $h= yd'y^{-1}$ where $x,y \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $d$ and $d'$ two diagonal matrices.

We have $gh = xdx^{-1}yd'y^{-1}$. This is clearly not with the form of product of an invertible matrix and diagonal matrix and the inverse of the first matrix.

But I wonder if there is better argument for this. I tried to think about an example in $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ but I didn't find.

Thanks in advance for your enlightements.

K. Y.

Comment: Why should $gh$ necessarily fail to be diagonalizable? What if $g$ and $h$ are already diagonal?

Comment: Presumably you mean not necessarily diagonalizable.

Comment: You're right, I meant not necessarilly diagonalizable. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \ne a^{-1}$, then 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & a \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
$$
is diagonalizable but
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & a \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is not valid; as suggested in the comments, just because $gh$ might have a form that is not diagonal, it does not imply that $gh$ is not diagonalizable.

An example of two matrices with determinant -1 multiplying to give a non-diagonal matrix is given in: [Is the product of any two invertible diagonalizable matrices diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084522/is-the-product-of-any-two-invertible-diagonalizable-matrices-diagonalizable)

You can multiply both matrices by -1 and that should give you your counterexamples.

Comment: Actually it isn't a good example because even if I multiply both matrices by -1 the determinant will remain -1, since det($\lambda g) = \lambda^n det(g)$ (here $n =2$ and $\lambda = -1$. Can you give me another example? Thanks.

Comment: Switch the columns of the first matrix and the rows of the second

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$